# Проверка доступа Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Работаю с RBAC на Yii, в документации сказано что проверить роль у пользователя вот так

Yii::$app->user->can('admin')

А как проверить роль не у текущего пользователя, а к примеру у выбранного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если известен id выбранного юзера, то как-то так:

```
Yii::$app->authManager->checkAccess($userId, 'admin')
```